# Reset to default slider value react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, slider

I try to create a reset button for the slider that will reset it to the initial value when pressed. My code doesn't show any error but the reset button doesn't work.

This is the Slider component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Slider,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  View} from 'react-native';
import {ButtonReset} from './ResetButton.js'


export class SliderRoll extends Component {

  state = {
    value: 1,
  };

  resetSliderValue = () => this.setState({value : 1})

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Slider style={styles.slider}
          minimumTrackTintColor={'blue'}
          maximumTrackTintColor={'red'}
          maximumValue = {2}
          value= {this.state.value}
          step={0.5}
          onValueChange={(value) => this.setState({value: value})} 
        />

        <ButtonReset resetSliderValue = {this.state.resetSliderValue}/>
        <Text style={styles.text} >
          {this.state.value}
        </Text> 

      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection:'column',
    width: 150,
    backgroundColor: 'pink',
    marginLeft: 50,
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  slider: {
    width: 150,
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontWeight: '500',
  },
})
```

This is the Reset button:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';

export class ButtonReset extends Component{
    render(){
      return(
        <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.container}
            onPress= {this.props.resetSliderValue}>
          <Image
            style={styles.button}
            source={require('./restart.png')}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        width: 50,
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'pink',
        marginLeft: 50,
        marginTop: 10,
    },
    button: {
        width:50,
        height:50,
        transform: [
            {scale: 1}
        ] 
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the problematic piece that stuck out right away:

`<ButtonReset resetSliderValue = {this.state.resetSliderValue}/>`

I believe it should be:

`<ButtonReset resetSliderValue = {this.resetSliderValue}/>`

Also, I believe you need to bind `this` so you can access `this` for setting state in the `resetSliderValue` function. I personally like to bind this once in the constructor for any functions that require it so no unnecessary rebinding during rendering:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.resetSliderValue = this.resetSliderValue.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: I think `this` binding will not be necessary as he has used ES7 syntax.

Comment: thank you your answer works perfectly. I also have another question: is it possible to pass a props to be a state on the child. For example: on the child component I define  state = {this.props.example}

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You can initialize the value of state to something from props. If props change then it won't update the state unless you monitor for it and handle the update in `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method.